# Combine two base class instances into a derived one

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have the following classes I used to define a tree structure with a number of specific nodes

```
class TreeNode
{
  std::vector<TreeNode*> children;
}
class BTNode: public virtual TreeNode
{
  virtual bool loadAttributes(XML) = 0;
  virtual BTState tick() = 0;

  void otherFunction1() { used by all the different nodes}
  void otherFunction2() { also used by all the node types }
}
```

There are a couple of specific implementations of the BTNode class that can be saved and loaded from XML files:

```
class BTSpecificNodeOne: public BTNode
{
  bool loadAttributes(XML) { load node specific data from XML }
  BTState tick() { specific implementation goes here }
}
class BTSpecificNodeTwo: public BTNode
{
  bool loadAttributes(XML) { load node specific data from XML }
  BTState tick() { specific implementation goes here }
}
etc.
```

I also have a genetic algorithm that optimises this tree structure based on a common tree node genome type:

```
class TreeNodeGenome: public virtual TreeNode
{
  bool load(XML);
  TreeNodeGenome* crossover(TreeNodeGenome* other);
  virtual void mutate() = 0;
}
```

Furthermore, to have the node specific implementation used within the genome

```
class BTSpecificNodeGenomeOne: public BTSpecificNode, public TreeNodeGenome
{
  void mutate() { node specific implementation }
}
class BTSpecificNodeGenomeTwo: public BTSpecificNode, public TreeNodeGenome
{
  void mutate() { node specific implementation }
}
etc.
```

I'd like to be able to save and load the results of the optimisation to/from an XML file.

The implementations of BTSpecificNodeOne, BTSpecificNodeTwo, etc. already have a save/load function that I use for saving the results, but loading them is a bit more tricky.

The load function of the BTNode class rebuilds the tree (from XML) based on the BTNode class (nodes may create children that are also loaded recursively). In order to use it again in the genetic algorithm, I need the nodes to derive from the TreeNodeGenome class as well.

I can rebuild a TreeNodeGenome structure based only on the information contained in TreeNode, but I'm not sure how to "merge" these two trees together.

I know that I could pretty much copy the load functions into the BTSpecificNodeGenomeOne, BTSpecificNodeGenomeTwo, etc. classes but I was wondering if there is a simpler/cleaner way to do it?

**EDIT:** Apparently what I'd like to do is a bit unclear from my previous post.

I have implemented a Behaviour Tree(BT) class, which uses a number of different nodes deriving from BTNode: Selector, Sequence, different condition and action nodes. The BT itself is saved in an XML format and can be loaded via BTNode::loadAttributes().

In addition to this, I have a genetic algorithm that can optimise tree structures. TreeNodeGenome implements the genetic operators of the different nodes to be used during evolution.

During evolution I use  BTSpecificNodeGenomeOne, BTSpecificNodeGenomeTwo nodes that implement both the different BT nodes and the genetic operators from TreeNodeGenome. TreeNodeGenome requires only the *structure* of the tree already encoded in the TreeNode base class and the node specific implementations of the mutation operator. As the BT and an evolvable tree structure are two conceptually different things, I'd like to keep them separate.

My question is: I have the BTNode::loadAttributes() function implemented for all BTNodes already, which load the BT from an XML file. This function creates its children as BTNodes, which are not evolvable. If I want to use the loaded tree in evolution, I need to somehow "merge" it with a TreeNodeGenome object.

I can do this by reimplementing the loadAttributes function in each derived BTSpecificNodeGenome, but I was wondering if there was a cleaner/simpler way to do this?

Comment: Not sure if I understood the problem, but couldn't you just let `TreeNodeGenome` derive from `BTNode`?

Comment: I don't think i really understood the problem either. I'd like to add that the simpler/cleaner solution, will usually be to redifne your class layout. And lay out your classes based on function. That way you might have to merge some classes. Which is elaborate, but it is the simplest. If you don't feel like doing that i think you might want to have a look at private inheritance and exposing a selection of members.

Comment: @m.s. In principle I could, but I wanted to separate `TreeNodeGenome`, which is meant to be a general tree node for optimising tree structures and `BTNode`, which is a specific tree structure with its own functions that can be optimised, but can also just be specified manually. In principle after the optimisation, I'm interested in having a `BTNode` structure only.

Comment: @laurisvr  as I just explained in my previous comment, the reason why I came up with this complicated class structure is exactly the functionality they express. I wanted to have the option to optimise _any_ tree structure with `TreeNodeGenome`, while `BTNode` is a specific implementation of _a_ tree structure. Therefore ex. `BTSpecificNodeGenomeOne` is a specific tree node that can be used in the optimisation. I hope this clear things up a bit ...

Comment: Okay so what is your actual goal then? And do you want every class to inherit `TreeNodeGenome`? The usual approach for a case like this is a default node class, which performs all the xml related tasks and maybe has a virtual function or two. Then the actual classes could derive from this class.

Comment: @laurisvr I want all BTSpecificNodeGenomes to inherit TreeNodeGenome, but not _all_ classes. See my edit for some extra details.

Comment: Then I would indeed create a class that derives both from `TreeNodeGenome` and from `BTSpecificGenome`. That way you can just use the old classes in the constructor.